# Bumpers with Turtlebot 2

Tags: microcontroller, turtlebot2, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to use a safety controller with my turtlebot 2, so that I can take into account bumper's state when navigating.

Is there a safety controller that has been created for the turtlebot 2  or should I use the same one than for the kobuki base ?
Is there a nodelet manager started in turtlebot_bringup/minimal.launch ?

UPDATE :

When I tried to do this tutorial : http://www.ros.org/wiki/kobuki/Tutorials/Write%20your%20own%20controller%20for%20Kobuki using only the kobuki_node/minimal.launch it works. But I would like to use turtlebot_bringup/minimal.launch but no nodelet manager seems to be started...

Can someone help me ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57730/bumpers-with-turtlebot-2/) by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 395 on 2013-03-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2013-03-11**:
Should work - kobuki, turtlebot-kobuki and turtlebot-create all start nodelet managers with the name mobile_base_nodelet_manager. You can find the turtlebot nodelet manager in https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot/blob/master/turtlebot_bringup/launch/includes/kobuki/_mobile_base.launch

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2013-03-11**:
What version of the kobuki and turtlebot stacks do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi CarolineQ,

the safety controller for Kobuki also works with Turtlebot 2. However, you have to adapt the launch file a bit. This modified version of `kobuki_keyop/safe_keyop.launch` file should allow you to drive your turtlebot around with the safety controller watching over it.

```
<!--
  Keyop configuration for working with the default Turtlebot launcher (minimal.launch). 
 -->
<launch>
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="kobuki_safety_controller" args="load kobuki_safety_controller/SafetyControllerNodelet mobile_base_nodelet_manager">
    <remap from="kobuki_safety_controller/cmd_vel" to="cmd_vel_mux/input/safety_controller"/>
    <remap from="kobuki_safety_controller/events/bumper" to="mobile_base/events/bumper"/>
    <remap from="kobuki_safety_controller/events/cliff" to="mobile_base/events/cliff"/>
    <remap from="kobuki_safety_controller/events/wheel_drop" to="mobile_base/events/wheel_drop"/>
  </node>
  
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="keyop_vel_smoother" args="load yocs_velocity_smoother/VelocitySmootherNodelet mobile_base
_nodelet_manager">
    <rosparam file="$(find kobuki_keyop)/param/keyop_smoother.yaml" command="load"/>
    <remap from="keyop_vel_smoother/odometry" to="odom"/>
    <remap from="keyop_vel_smoother/smooth_cmd_vel" to="cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop"/>
  </node>
  
  <node pkg="kobuki_keyop" type="keyop" name="keyop" output="screen">
    <remap from="keyop/motor_power" to="mobile_base/commands/motor_power"/>
    <remap from="keyop/cmd_vel" to="keyop_vel_smoother/raw_cmd_vel"/>
    <param name="linear_vel_step"  value="0.05" type="double"/>
    <param name="linear_vel_max"   value="1.5"  type="double"/>
    <param name="angular_vel_step" value="0.33" type="double"/>
    <param name="angular_vel_max"  value="6.6"  type="double"/>
    <param name="wait_for_connection_" value="true" type="bool"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

The major difference between kobuki_node/minimal.launch and turtlebot_bringup/minimal.launch is, that the latter already starts the velocity muxer. That plus few adjustments to the topic remappings is all that is needed.

I suggest, you start with this launch file and adapt it to your needs.

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) with karma: 2062 on 2013-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-03-11**:
Yes I think this will work ! Thanks for the answer !